# Unable to save model using model.save('modelName')

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I trained a siamese model, now facing problem saving this model by using:

`siamese_model.save('siamesemodel.h5')`

Here is the code for siamese model :

```
def make_embedding():
    inp = Input(shape = (100, 100, 3), name = 'Input Image')

    #First Block
    c1 = Conv2D(64, (10, 10), activation = 'relu')(inp)
    m1 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding = 'same')(c1)

    #Second Block
    c2 = Conv2D(128, (7, 7), activation = 'relu')(m1)
    m2 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding = 'same')(c2)

    #Third Block
    c3 = Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation = 'relu')(m2)
    m3 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding = 'same')(c3)

    #Final Enbedding Block
    c4 = Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation = 'relu')(m3)
    f1 = Flatten()(c4)
    d1 = Dense(4096, activation = 'sigmoid')(f1)
    
    return Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [d1], name = 'Embedding' )

embedding = make_embedding()
```

```
class L1Dist(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    # Magic happens here
    def call(self, input_embedding, validation_embedding):
        return (input_embedding-validation_embedding)

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        config = { "sublayer": keras.saving.serialize_keras_object(self.sublayer),}
        return {**base_config, **config}
```

```
def make_siamese_model():

    # Handle Inputs
    # Anchor image input in the network
    input_image = Input(name = 'input_img', shape = (100, 100, 3))

    # Validation IMage in the network
    validation_image = Input(name = 'validation_img', shape = (100, 100, 3))

    # Combine L1Dist Component
    siamese_layer = L1Dist()
    siamese_layer._name = 'distance'
    distances = siamese_layer(embedding(input_image), embedding(validation_image))

    # Classification layer
    classifier = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(distances)

    return Model(inputs = [input_image, validation_image], outputs = classifier, name = 'siameseNetwork')
```

`siamese_model = make_siamese_model()`

`ERROR: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute 'saving'`

I also had problem laoding already saved siamese model, i tried loading the model using custom objects as shown below but it didn't work:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('siamesem_model.h5', custom_objects={'L1Dist':L1Dist, 'BinaryCrossentropy': tf.losses.binary_crossentropy})
```

`NameError: name 'L1Dist' is not defined`

Comment: The error module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute 'saving' is due to a typo in your L1Dist class definition. It should be keras.models.serialize instead of keras.saving.serialize_keras_object.
When you're trying to load the model, the error NameError: name 'L1Dist' is not defined occurs because the L1Dist class definition is needed before loading the model. Make sure you have defined the L1Dist class before calling load_model.